# how to add a new mib module on snmp agent on netgui

Tags: dns, snmp, net-snmp

I'm trying to add a mib module to my snmp agent but i'm missing something.

first I add the mib file to the folder /usr/share/snmp/mibs. The mib file its DNS-SERVER-MIB and I download it from [here](http://www.simpleweb.org/ietf/mibs/modules/IETF/txt/DNS-SERVER-MIB).

Then of that I add the mib to the tool [following steps](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/FAQ%3aApplications_02).

Now, When I use the command 
`snmptranslare 1.3.6.1.2.1.32`
And the answer is DNS-SERVER-MIB::dns.

Now, When I tip

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c local 127.0.0.1 .1.3.6.1.2.1.32
```

Show the output

> rt09:/usr/share/snmp# snmpwalk -v2c -c local 127.0.0.1 .1.3.6.1.2.1.32
>
> > DNS-SERVER-MIB::dns = No Such Object avaiable on this agent at this OUI

this is the my snmpd.conf file

> com2sec read            127.0.0.1       local
>
> com2sec readwrite
>
> 10.2.4.1        privada
>
> group   admin   v2c     readwrite
>
> group   all     v2c     read
>
> view    dns     included .iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2
>
> access  admin   ""      any     noauth  exact   dns     dns     none
>
> access  all     ""      any     noauth  exact   dns     none    none

If someone can help my I appreciate that

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic to automatically extend Net-SNMP by dropping the MIB document into that folder. You will have to write a new MIB module or use other extending methods. The following blog post does give hints and samples on how to extend Net-SNMP, and get you started,

http://vincent.bernat.im/en/blog/2012-extending-netsnmp.html