# Custom MIBs creation

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, asn.1, mib

For our VoIP application we have to publish some value through database on SNMP. Can anyone let me know how would do this.

Will I have to create MIBs and if that how would MIBs receive data from application. Is there any free editor for creating MIBs.

Or I would write a script in Perl or any other language that would read data from database and we will publish that data on SNMP. Please let me know how would I publish that data on SNMP using Perl script.

Thanks

Comment: Invalid close. The question is neither ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, nor rhetorical, and it *has* been answered in its current form. You could make a better case that it was off topic, but I can't think of an SE site where it would be on-topic.

Comment: @EJP not an invalid "on hold". The core question is if there is a free editor for creating MIBs, or if OP should "write scripts in Perl or any other language". Definitely not a question welcome in StackOverflow, for many reasons. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask. I voted to leave this question closed.

Comment: I think the question is absolutely "overly broad". The second and final sentences make my case. It could have been closed for other reasons as well.

Answer (score 1):

As I answered in [how to add a new mib module on snmp agent on netgui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17090455/how-to-add-a-new-mib-module-on-snmp-agent-on-netgui), you might try to extend net-snmp agent to achieve your goal.

To write a MIB document, you can simply use any text editor. There are many MIB editors also, but I don't know whether any of them is free.